# Ember.js - why is my View with inline template not displaying?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to get a view with an inline template to display inside a handlebars conditional. In my application code, it shows up if I navigate to another route and then back again. In the fiddle, I get an error about the view.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/418/)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>If you click that button, I might say 'Hello!'</h1>
        <button {{action 'click_me'}}>Click me</button>
        {{#if controller.new_visible}}
            {{#view App.MyView}}
                    Hello!            {{/view}}
        {{/if}}
</script>


var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    new_visible: false,
    actions: {
        click_me: function() {
            alert('You clicked me!');
            this.set('new_visible',true);
        }
    }
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    })
  })
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App` must be a global - if you check the javascript log, you can see that the handlebars view helper can't find a view named `App.MyView`. That's because `App` is being declared locally, so the template can't get to it. Change the `App` definition to this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
```

Also, you don't need to extend the router. You can just use map. e.g.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/420/